# Working 'return' statement in 'return throw new Error()'

Tags: javascript

This couldn't be necessary but I'm curious.

When I used `throw` statement I used to use with return like this.

```
return throw new Error('...')
```

I know there's no need the `return` but it's working well so I've used this clearly.

Is there a difference between `throw` and `return throw` statements?

Comment: I can't recreate your scenario, I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw`

Comment: I used Meteor.js platform, and it's possible in Method-Call connection. But I think @Quentin's answer might be right on the normal JS grammar.

Answer (score 4):

The `throw` keyword is not allowed after a `return` keyword.

`return throw new Error("...");` throws an exception, but not the Error object you are trying to create, it throws *SyntaxError: Unexpected token throw* instead.

Comment: I think it might be working because of Meteor.js Methods function. But your answer seems like reasonable- Thanks-